# Can't get multi-model form to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an `Appointment` model where each `Appointment` has a `client_id`. When an `Appointment` is created, I want the user to be able to type the client's name into an autocomplete field so a new `Client` is created if the name the user typed in doesn't already have a `Client` record. (I've done this exact same thing in other frameworks.)

Here's what my `Appointment` model looks like:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointment_services
  belongs_to :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

And here's what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
  <% if @appointment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@appointment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this appointment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @appointment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :client do |client_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= client_form.label :name %>
      <%= client_form.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

For some reason nothing inside `<%= f.fields_for :client do...` shows up on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.fields_for @client do |client_form| %>
```

and don't forget to initialize `@client` in your controller